# Bootstrap with Gulp app won't launch from Heroku

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, gulp

I have a web site built with Bootstrap and Gulp on a NodeJS framework. Gulp basically just compiles changes and routes things, but isn't a server. I have my `package.json` file scripts section set to run Gulp on start. I have pushed everything to Github and then to Heroku for deployment. When I try to launch it from Heroku, nothing happens. I just get the following message: `An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.` Below is the log and my `package.json` file. Do I need to go back and add something like Express/server.js just to get it to run (with dynamic port setting)?

```
{
  "name": "bs4starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bootstrap 4 workflow",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "author": "Justin Bridwell",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
   "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
   "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
   "jquery": "^3.2.1",
   "popper.js": "^1.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the Heroku log:

```
 2018-02-20T21:46:01.209374+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the 
 bs4starter@1.0.0 start script.
 2018-02-20T21:46:01.209612+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not 
 a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 2018-02-20T21:46:01.223672+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2018-02-20T21:46:01.224004+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of 
 this run can be found in:
 2018-02-20T21:46:01.224195+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     
 /app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-20T21_46_01_217Z-debug.log
 2018-02-23T14:23:21.846098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=polar-caverns-
 42095.herokuapp.com request_id=5e788478-e16d-4f2e-a060-106ab9ec81ed 
 fwd="73.147.231.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
 protocol=https
 2018-02-23T14:23:22.058194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-caverns-
 42095.herokuapp.com request_id=0833d754-afce-48fd-94f7-25900fb9d4cd 
 fwd="73.147.231.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
 protocol=https
 2018-02-26T21:26:20.770745+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=polar-caverns-
 42095.herokuapp.com request_id=6fc50be9-40aa-4922-9a76-955947e78478 
 fwd="73.147.231.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
 protocol=https
 2018-02-26T21:26:21.390897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-caverns-
 42095.herokuapp.com request_id=73f17c20-7aa3-48d0-86df-5bd5f4dea85a 
 fwd="73.147.231.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
 protocol=https
 2018-02-27T13:31:51.110344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=polar-caverns-
 42095.herokuapp.com request_id=06f192f8-c5a2-4327-bef1-dc3d9dfa27b2 
 fwd="73.147.231.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
 protocol=https
 2018-02-27T13:31:51.317319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-caverns-
 42095.herokuapp.com request_id=c02a6c07
 -98f4-4b3e-b2c6-c3636e6123e9 fwd="73.147.231.118" dyno= connect= service= 
 status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: You "don't see anything under the Heroku log"? Does this mean literally nothing? The log should show whether or not the node site started successfully. Do you have .procfile to tell Heroku where to start the app?

Comment: OK, I found the log data and edited the question. It seems that there is a problem with the start script in my package.json file, but I'm not sure what I need to do here. It works fine on local.

Comment: And did you look at `/app/.npm/_logs/2018-02-20T21_46_01_217Z-debug.log` as the log says?

Comment: How do I get to that file? Sorry, I am new and its not something I see in the the web site folder. Can it be accessed through the Heroku dashboard somehow?